# All possible solutions to an easy PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, linear-pde

Given a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$, consider the following system of differential equations:
$$ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \quad,\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y) = \alpha\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)
$$
for a given $\alpha>0$. What are all possible solutions $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ ?

---

The followings are not solutions:
$$ u(x,y)=f(x,\alpha\,y)+C $$
or
$$ u(x,y)=\alpha\,f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\,x,y\right)+C \;.$$
Thanks @TedShifrin

Comment: Be careful here. When you write the original PDEs, it is assumed that you evaluate the functions at the same point $(x,y)$ on both sides of the equation, is it not?

Comment: Well, if we've agreed on that, neither of your proposed solutions works!

Comment: @TedShifrin ops.. you are right! So I am even further from the solution

Comment: It is not free that a solution even exists. Consider that if you add some extra regularity then existence needs $f_{xy}=0$ or $\alpha=1$. If you assume $f_{xy}=0$ then the question is interesting.

Comment: Yes, I was about to add that if $f\in C^2$, then we see that we need $f_{xy} = 0$ (unless it's the stupid case $\alpha = 1$). @Ian got there faster. Well, if $f_{xy} = 0$ on $\Bbb R^2$, you should be able to write $f$ in a helpful form.

Comment: Ok, let's assume $f,u\in C^2$, $\alpha\neq1$ and $f_{xy}\neq0$. How can you prove there are no solutions? The case $f_{x,y}=0$ simply gives $u(x,y)=f_1(x)+\alpha f_2(y)+C$ where $f(x,y) = f_1(x)+f_2(y)$.

Comment: Understood: it sufficies to compute $f_{x,y}$ in two ways and compare them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume $f\in C^2$ and $\alpha\ne 1$, you deduce that $f_{xy}=0$, from which you conclude that $f(x,y) = g(x)+h(y)$ for some $C^1$ functions $g$ and $h$. Then $u(x,y)= g(x)+\alpha h(y)$ gives the general solution (you can absorb the constant).

Now, can you show that $f$ takes this form without assuming $f\in C^2$?

What happens if $\alpha = 1$?